# What is the difference between ASA 5505 Security Appliance and without Security Appliance

Tags: firewalls, cisco

Considering the two devices, [ASA 5505 Security Appliance](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000JVTTPM) and [without Security Appliance](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000O0Z8GC).

What are the differences between having security appliance and without security appliance?

I can not find the datasheet without security appliance and no compare facility exists on the official website.

Does it mean that without security appliance, the device does not have software? If so, which software? ASDM?

Comment: While not asked directly, consider that the ASA 5505 has had its end of sale and end of life dates announced. As of August 25, 2017 the ASA 5505 is no longer purchasable through *official* Cisco distribution channels. https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/security/asa-5505-adaptive-security-appliance/eos-eol-notice-c51-738642.html The ASA 5506-X is the recommended replacement from Cisco but comes with its own set of challenges and deviations from the way the 5505 functioned (of relevant note the 5506-X lacks a built-in hardware switch).

Answer (score 1):

> What are the differences between having security appliance and without security appliance?

Bad listing information by a seller on Amazon. Seriously, there is no ASA (Adaptive Security Appliance) without a security appliance.

You can find the datasheet for the ASA-5505 on Cisco's website [here](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/security/asa-5500-series-next-generation-firewalls/datasheet-c78-733510.html). On "Table 2" you will find the ordering information which includes both the part numbers referenced on the Amazon website that indicates what is included.

This product line has already had it's [EoS/EoL announcement](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/security/asa-5505-adaptive-security-appliance/eos-eol-notice-c51-738642.html) and has already passed the last ship date from Cisco (i.e. Cisco is no longer manufacturing these or providing them to distributors). What you will find now is the stock that individual sellers had on hand before this point...some will raise the price to take advantage of the limited availability, others will drop the price to get them out of inventory faster. You will also see more of these appearing on the used market.

Answer (score 0):

The ASA-5505 is a security appliance, aka firewall/router with basic packet inspection. Base is a unit limited to an internal network, a DMZ, WAN and 10 internal devices using it to access the external WAN. The price goes up with each added feature whether it's more users, unrestricted internal networks or added security plugin card.

The difference in price on the two units you listed is because the ASA5505-BUN-K9 is 10 user and the ASA5505-UL-BUN-K9 is unlimited user.

They tend to come in 10 user, 50 user and Unlimited.

Once you buy one and get access to Cisco's support website, you find that the ASA-5505 is generically referred to as the ASA-5505 Security Appliance.

The ASA-5505 comes with the proprietary Cisco router software and ASDM management software installed.

Comment: The problem with this answer is you haven't explained what "10 user" "50 user" means, I think it would benefit the OP.

Answer (score -3):

The Security Appliance is practically the Firepower module of the ASA.

What that means:

Blank ASA has the basic firewall functionality and only that.

The ASA with Firepower additionally has many more capabilities like:

- URL filtering
- Intrusion Prevention System
- File Filtering

Note that you can use ASDM for management in both cases.

Comment: I don't think you're correct here. I believe this is just bad description from the seller. If it included Firepower it would say "With firepower services". How can you have an Adaptive Security Appliance without the Security Appliance? "Security Appliance" is not a synonym for "Firepower" in the Cisco world. This is purely bad description from the seller.

Comment: Yes, the description is bad but that's what the seller probably wanted to say.

Comment: No, I don't think so. As I said, "Security Appliance" is not a synonym for "Firepower" also by that logic; the one without the "security appliance" should cost less, yet it costs more. Considering Firepower is an extra module which requires extra licensing you'd expect the one with "security appliance" to cost more not the other way around.

Comment: Anything is possible if they messed-up, including the pricing.

Comment: It still doesn't answer how they can sell an "Advance Security Appliance" without the "Security Appliance". I don't deem your answer to be correct at all. To add - just because they messed up the name, I don't think they would get the pricing wrong, it's two completely different things.

Comment: The 5505 was released before Cisco acquired Firepower. As such there is absolutely no tie in with Firepower in this product.

Comment: Well if we think that way, Cisco ASA 5505 is an Adaptive Security Appliance, so the initial question does not make any sense.